# onselectstart() function on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

```
document.body.onselectstart = function() {
   return false;
}
```

I have this part of code in my `windows.onload = function start()`funtion. When I drag my mouse on top to down my context is not selecting. However If I drag my mouse from the bottom to top I can select whatever I want. Is there a way to prevent both dragging from top to bottom and reverse?

Full code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body oncontextmenu="return false;">

    Value:<br> <p id="Value"> 0 </p>

    <p>Click the ball to increase the value.</p>

    <input type="image" onmousedown="increase()" src="RedBall.png" id="demp" style="position:relative; left: 500px; top: 80px; width: 32px; height: 32px;" />


    <script>
      function increase() {
        var x = document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML;
        var increased = parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(1,10);
        document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML = increased;
      }

      function change(){
        var num = 0;
        window.setInterval(function(){
          var speedx= Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) - 5);
          var speedy= Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) - 5);
          document.getElementById("demp").style.left= parseInt(document.getElementById("demp").style.left, 10) + parseInt(speedx,10) +"px"; 
          document.getElementById("demp").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("demp").style.top, 10) + parseInt(speedy,10) +"px"; 
        }, 10)
      }
      window.onload = function start() {
        change();
        document.body.onselectstart = function() {
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://output.jsbin.com/niyijuqaco

You can also see the result on this site

Comment: Can you add a snippet or bin?

Comment: @MoshFeu I add full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**

The `body` tag not take the place for all the window:

[image]

**The solution**
Well, the solution is simple. You need to set the height of the `html` (just for be endure) and the `body` to `100%`.

[image]

Now, the `body` take the size of the window and the event `onselectstart` firing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height:100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body oncontextmenu="return false;">

    Value:<br> <p id="Value"> 0 </p>

    <p>Click the ball to increase the value.</p>

    <input type="image" onmousedown="increase()" src="RedBall.png" id="demp" style="position:relative; left: 500px; top: 80px; width: 32px; height: 32px;" />


    <script>
      function increase() {
        var x = document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML;
        var increased = parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(1,10);
        document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML = increased;
      }

      function change(){
        var num = 0;
        window.setInterval(function(){
          var speedx= Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) - 5);
          var speedy= Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) - 5);
          document.getElementById("demp").style.left= parseInt(document.getElementById("demp").style.left, 10) + parseInt(speedx,10) +"px"; 
          document.getElementById("demp").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("demp").style.top, 10) + parseInt(speedy,10) +"px"; 
        }, 10)
      }
      window.onload = function start() {
        change();
        document.body.onselectstart = function() {
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck.